# print(sys.argv) doesn't take arguments

Tags: python, windows, sys

that's probably a pretty dumb question, but I'm a beginner programmer and i can't get this.

basically, i think im using sys.argv wrong because it just doesn't take arguments as much as i can tell. the first code i've written with sys.argv looks like this:

```
import sys
import pyperclip

dict = {'email': 'foo',
        'blog': 'monty',
        'briefcase': 666,
        'stack overflow': 'pulp'}
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('no arguments')
    sys.exit()
account = sys.argv[1]
if account in dict:
    pyperclip.copy(dict[account])
else:
    print('no value found under' + account)
```

saved it under the name pw.py and tried to use it via command prompt by typing in

```
pw.py email
```

but no matters what i type it returns 'no arguments'. the second program i tried going simple and just giving it a simple print function:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

this one just returns the path to the program. what am i doing wrong?

i get that this a noob question, and that this is a horrible way to save passwords, this is for a project I'm doing trying to learn python by myself.

Comment: What environment are you running the program in? From `bash` under Linux, or from ... whatever Windows uses, or something else?

Comment: using windows, sorry i didn't specify. fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ' python pw.py email ' for the first script
and for the second 'python pw.py any_args'

Comment: How different is this from running it as an executable?

Comment: @SilentMonk its different because when you run it as an executable you are providing only one argument for the first script. And for the second script, only the file name.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is. But it is working as expected whether it is run as an executable or python <script>. Moreover the arguments are passed to this script and not to Python.

Comment: @SilentMonk The difference is... Windows. Windows is retarded. That's the difference. For some reason it doesn't pass on arguments if you don't run the script as `python whatever.py some_arg`.

Comment: @Rawing, thanks for the info. I will add the windows tag to the question.

Comment: Users inadvertently or intentionally modify the filetype association that Python's installer configures, either directly via "open with" or indirectly by installing some IDE that improperly takes over .py files. Then they fix it via the "open with" menu, but instead of selecting the existing Python ProgId from the available choices, they navigate to the installation folder to open with python.exe. This creates an automatic ProgId that's designed for opening data files, not scripts, and thus only passes the `"%1"` file but not the remaining `%*` parameters.